# Cloth sim does not stay with rig during animation

Tags: animation, rigging, cloth-simulation

I have rigged my character and I parented a cloth simmed cloak to the rig. I can move the character to a different location but as soon as I play the animation, the cloak snaps back to the origin but still animates as if it's still on the character.

I have parented the animated cloak to my rig. At this point, I can change the pose and the cloak will react properly.

[image: Image number 1]

Still on frame 1, I've moved the entire rig back to the position I want him to start.

[image: Image number 2]

Now, when I move 1 frame forward, the cloak moves to the cursor. The origin point stays with the rig.

[image: Image number 3]

I know it has to be something simple. Just can't figure it out. I'm still a noob.

Here's a [video showing what I mean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNL0xxiEF6U).

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will add some screenshots. I'm still kind of new so it's difficult to articulate what I want to say. I will try to add more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the cloth sim animation cache. Animate your character. Re-bake cloth sim.